# Can't produce a flattened record from nested xml with 0-n child elements using Spark-xml

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am working with xml structure something like below:

```
<flow>
    <request>
        <user>
            <id></id>
            <url></url>
    </request>
    <app_details>
        <id></id>
        <op></op>
        <seq></seq>
    </app_details>
    <service>
        <details></details>
        <application>
            <abc></abc>
            <abc></abc>
            <abc></abc>
            <xyz>
                <lmn></lmn>
            </xyz>
            <applicant cd_type='Principle'>
                <individual>
                    <name1></name1>
                    <name2></name2>
                    <email></email>
                    <dt_dob></dt_dob>
                </individual>
            </applicant>
            <applicant cd_type='Y'>
                <individual>
                    <name1></name1>
                    <name2></name2>
                    <email></email>
                    <dt_dob></dt_dob>
                </individual>
            </applicant>
        </app>
    </service>
</flow>
```

This basically translates into: 1 'application' can have multiple 'applicants' and then every 'applicant' has child element 'individual'.

I am using Spark-xml to read this xml. I want to extract all the 'individuals' along with 'application_id' and 'cd_type' from higher in the hierarchy.

```
spark.read.format('xml').option("rowTag", "flow").option("attributePrefix","_Att_").option("multiLine", "true").option("mode", "FAILFAST").option("inferSchema", False).load(xml_path)
```

Below is my select statement to read the specific values:

```
df2.select(col('app_details.id').alias('id'),explode(col('service.application.applicant._Att_cd_type')).alias('cd_type'), col('service.application.applicant.individual.dt_dob').alias('dt_dob'))
```

Below is the output:

```
application_id  cd_type     dt_dob
59900XX         Principal   ["1938-12-02"]
62CCTT          Principal   ["1928-10-01"]
FB4499          Principal   ["1916-01-08","1936-01-09"]
```

Since the xml can have multiple applicants and individuals, my select statement returns all the instances of child elements. I have solved it for 'cd_type' which is at applicant level by exploding it. Next is dt_dob which is further down and the result set above shows multiple 'dt_dobs' when more than one 'applicants' whereas I only want one dt_dob of the 'individual' being traversed and not all individuals for that application.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the applicants in a first step and then select the required columns from each applicant in a second step:

```python
df2.select(F.col('app_details.id').alias('id'), \
    F.explode(F.col('service.application.applicant')).alias('applicant')) \
   .select('id', 'applicant._Att_cd_type', 'applicant.individual.dt_dob')
```